# Convert Object Array to JSON String on Android

Tags: android, arrays, json

I can't seem to find this anywhere, but tons of people have to be doing this.

I have an array of objects that I want to convert to a JSON String and post to a REST URL. Here's what I have so far:

```
    if(history==null||history.length == 0){
        return new String[0];
    }

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    for(DeviceHistory connectHistory:history){
        array.put(connectHistory);
    }

    JSONObject response = jsonClient.remoteCall(SERVICE_NAME, array.toString());
```

The problem is that I get ["com.abc.model.connect.DeviceHistory@41e63298","com.abc.model.connect.DeviceHistory@41e63760","com.abc.model.connect.DeviceHistory@41e63c28","com.abc.model.connect.DeviceHistory@41e640f0"] from array.toString(). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is the result of `Object.toString()`. You may want to try:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

This library allows to convert Object to JSON and back.

Comment: You're wrong as to why it's happening, but I ended up solving it using the Gson libraries.

Comment: By casting here I mean result of Object.toString()

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are not passing your object as a String, so what you are writing in your JSON is a reference to your object.

You should implement your `toString()` method in that class if you can or just use it. However, if you cant you will need a helper method to achieve it.